# Issue Populating Listview in Fragment with ListAdapter causes Error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Im trying to populate a listview in a Fragment, however im getting a NullPointerException.

I believe i may be implementing the ListAdapter incorrectly below:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                       getActivity(), inboxList,
                                        R.layout.women_list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_FROM,TAG_DATE,TAG_EMAIL,TAG_SUBJECT},
                                        new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date,R.id.mail,R.id.roundscore });
                                // updating listview
                         list1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**View Full Fragment Code here:** http://pastebin.com/33x7Zet2

## Error:

09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): java.lang.NullPointerException 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PagesFragment$LoadInbox$1.run(PagesFragment.java:291) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4673) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PagesFragment$LoadInbox.onPostExecute(PagesFragment.java:273) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PagesFragment$LoadInbox.onPostExecute(PagesFragment.java:1) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 09-22 07:11:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

View Code: http://pastebin.com/33x7Zet2

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate for: "What is a Null Pointer Exception". seriously?

Comment: you can easily debug the null pointer exception click the logcat report on line runOnUiThread...If I am not wrong then your TextView must be throwing null pointer exception...neyways you can apply debug pointer and get the line where you are getting error...Also this time you got new error...it seems you solved list error :)

Comment: Ha thanks Shadow from one issue to another :)